# Size in bytes that a json doc occupied stored

Tags: json, elasticsearch, utf-8, byte

When storing a JSON in Elastic Search, how much space does it take?
E.g if for example I store a JSON that has `1000` chars total (including whitespace/formatting) how many bytes does it take to be stored in Elastic Search as a doc?